# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device in Ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, pip

I am trying to install some libraries using pip in my Ubuntu 22 VM but I get the error below.

I install the package  using

```
pip -r requirements.txt
```

then it installs some packages then throws the below error

```
Collecting xgboost (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Using cached xgboost-1.7.5-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (200.3 MB)
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

I have tried to check the disk space using the below command

```
df -h
```

and the output is below

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       9.6G  9.3G  210M  98% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.6G  964K  1.6G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda15      105M  6.1M   99M   6% /boot/efi
tmpfs           795M  4.0K  795M   1% /run/user/1001
```

and even tried to export the tmp directory from the home directory
`export TMPDIR='/var/tmp'`

Any help on how I can resolve the issue

Comment: `/` has 210M of free memory, xgboost alone has 200M. You mentioned installing several liibraries, so you are quickly running out of storage here. Can you make it more clear what your question is? Are you asking how to increase the disk space of `/`?

Comment: Both `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` are on `/` filesystem that don't have enough space.

Comment: The root file system is running out of free space while installing the package. Back up the persistent disk first and then resize it larger.